# Can't delete install directories inside my own user home

Tags: windows-vista

Somewhere in the recent past something has changed on my Windows Vista 64 bit desktop to where I can't delete certain folders.  I had started cleaning out some old files prior to starting backing things up, but it seems I *can't* delete things that I *should* be able to...

It seems that folders that are left behind as part of any install process, some quite a while back, have a read-only bit set on the folder properties, and I can't delete them.  I change the properties, hit 'Apply', and exit the Properties dialog... and I'm right back where I started.  Upon inspection, the folders have the read-only bit set again.

Any ideas/suggestions - beyond blowing away Windows entirely?  (if it wasn't for certain games, I would, trust me!)

Answer (score 1):

Run cmd.exe as a `Administrator` and use `rmdir /S c:\damnfolderdie\` 
or if you want gui run from same cmd.exe `notepad.exe` instead, select open file and delete that folder via `open dialog`.

It's kind of workaround, but it's working so...

Comment: Yeah... still not working.  This deletes the *files* inside the problem folders, which is a step in the right direction... but the folders are still there... *all* of them.

Comment: Sorry, my fault it's `rmdir /s c:\damnfolderdie\`.

Comment: Still not working... now it's telling me 'Access is denied'.

Comment: Then it's a time for [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/), it's an utility which can delete files and folders which are opened by another programs.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, also semi-work around, would be to use a registry tweak to "take ownership".

I assume you are an admin, and as such - you can follow [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) to get you there.

All you need to do is download the reg files, double click to install, say yes, and then right click on any folders that you cannot delete, select "Take Ownership" and then you should be free to do your bidding.

Comment: Yeah... already tried that.  Doesn't work.  Gives exactly the same results as before - tells me I don't have permission to delete those files.

Comment: Very odd.  Sorry to provide a useless answer, I didn't see you say anything about it above.

Comment: NP... I hadn't mentioned it because nothing had happened and I'd forgotten about it.